# access 2013, how to oppen my access application with a mode shar

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 application that will be used by multiple users. but the problem that this application opens in exclusive mode and 2 person can not opens the same time. how I can make this usable application several times simultaneously. I tried the shared mode in customer parameter but it does not change . thank you

Comment: i need  help please!!

Comment: WARNING !! where are you plesae?  I need help for my application!!